# How to use Conditional Formatting?

Tags: excel

How can I write a conditional formatting formula that will highlight the values in col. C is the value in B is a "Y"

I've tried to research this problem, but cannot find an answer.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The rule will be:

```
=$B1="Y"
```

The "Applied to Range" is:

```
=$C$1:$C$1000
```

Note: You can change the start row to whatever you want. Just make sure the rule and applied-to range start on the same row, otherwise it'll be off.